# can I get warnings for name conflicts (shadowing) in mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

If a local variable has the same name as an argument, the argument is overridden (shadowed). If the local variable is not initialized it will be NULL, regardless of the value passed through the argument. I had a procedure with that situation (below) and there was no warning or error. Is there some setting that will give warnings or errors if variables are shadowed?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`dev`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_empErrShadow`(in idVar int)
BEGIN
DECLARE idVar INT;  -- ERROR shadows arg idVar, get null value (name conflict)

insert into Employees values (idVar, 28, 'ttt', 'lastname');

-- try get warning about variable shadow. Doesn't work
show errors;  
show warnings;
END
```

Using MySQL 5.7 but 8.0 is the same according to documentation. 
*Name Conflicts within Stored Routines* in 
[MySQL :: MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual :: 23.8 Restrictions on Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use consistent naming conventions instead:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`dev`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_empErrShadow` (
    in in_idVar int
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE p_idVar INT;  -- ERROR shadows arg idVar, get null value (name conflict)

    insert into Employees values (in_idVar, 28, 'ttt', 'lastname');

    -- try get warning about variable shadow. Doesn't work
    show errors;  
    show warnings;
END;
```

Such consistency will help you prevent the errors yourself.